# I scored low on the Technical Test, but they offered me a Job?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, failure

I interviewed for a PHP Developer's position earlier in the week, my experience is in C#, so my knowledge of PHP is extremely limited.

But I went for the position anyway, because if I didn't turn up I'd never have the opportunity to at least have a go at getting the job.

It turns out that as expected I failed miserably on the technical test, However they said they loved my attitude towards learning PHP, my work ethic and also that my previous experience in C# means that PHP wouldn't be difficult to pick up, so they offered me the Job there and then, in the Interview! (Which I was told has never happened).

So my question is, could this be too good to be true? I'm having a few doubts about the position considering they heavily rely on a language I don't know very well, am I going to be out of a job within a few months of starting? I'd just like some opinions please, it would help greatly

Comment: sometimes you should not be too critical of yourself. maybe they see you are a smart guy/gal who can things done. All you need to do is learn php and apply it under the guidance of senior developers. OR, maybe the actual job they give you might not be so good. Keep your other job interviews and offers as a back up.

Comment: Not all technical tests are to determine if you have the skills to do the job. They can be often used to gauge your level of knowledge in the event they need to up skill you, or if there are other roles which are a better fit. 

That said, being offered a job on the spot seems a bit off.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's quite possible that they are being perfectly honest with you.  I would never hire someone or not based on the particular technical skill needed for the job today, as what will be needed tomorrow might well be something different.  I want someone who's a fast learner, and has a great attitude and aptitude for learning new things.

*Are* you a quick learner?  Have you worked in languages other than C# before?

I think they've giving you a chance to put your money where your mouth is.  If you are interested in the job, go for it.  But do your very best to come up to speed quickly (possibly including spending time outside of work hours developing your skills).

Comment: Well said, all of it; and I would add that they may have simply liked your personality. Sometimes (often, actually) that's more important than your technical skills.

Comment: Thanks for this; i think the term "Hit the nail on the head" is most appropriate here =]

Comment: It is incredibly difficult to hire good people.  Likely the OP missed on some of the technical details but showed enough that it was obvious that just a little training would round him/her out.  I'd hire that person in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are lucky that you found a company that doesn't simply look at test scores but actually the *potential of the employee*.

They saw your potential to succeed with them and that's why they hired you.

From a technical standpoint, picking up PHP if you are fluent in C# is a very easy task, and I'm sure they understand this.

I would rather hire a resource that is quick to learn new skills (not a trivial task), than someone who is a superstar but can only do one thing.  What if tomorrow I need them to do something else?  The cost of hiring (and on-boarding) is the most expensive part of any business, so they don't want to do this often.

I say go for it!

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, could this be too good to be true? I'm having a few
>   doubts about the position considering they heavily rely on a language
>   I don't know very well, am I going to be out of a job within a few
>   months of starting?

So you were offered a job, given great reasons why they like you - and you are still worried.

If you have confidence in your own abilities, stop worrying so much!

As they indicated, they feel you will be able to learn PHP. They are correctly saying that in the bigger scheme of things, knowing the specific language is far, far less important than being a great worker, with a great attitude, a great work ethic, and being able to learn.

This is an indication that this company gets it, in my opinion. They understand what is important, and are willing to help employees learn the attributes they don't already hold. Unfortunately, not every company is smart enough to understand this.

In the software business things change rapidly. Programming languages come and go fairly rapidly. It's important to be a lifelong learner.

You are being offered a chance to show that you can be more than just a "C# person". If you take that change and do well with another language, you'll be able to show yourself and all future employers that you are more than just a one-trick pony - that you are someone who can learn and adjust.

I think you should view this offer as "a really good chance", rather than "too good".